# sort order preference is lost on second page of job results

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If you filter developer jobs by "newest" and go to 2 (pagination), the sort option is reset, and the jobs are once again sorted by "matches", meaning you can't ever possibly see the latest jobs apart from the first paginated list.

Comment: Fix on its way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up - I pushed a minor change on Friday that tweaked some canonical URL generation, tested that the first page of sort orders worked and neglected to test that paging was OK because I'm a bad person. I've just pushed a fix to address this and everything now functions as expected.